# Advent of Code Day 2 - Javascript Array Processing Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am currently completing the Day 2 challenge of Advent of Code and noticed that when I convert the given challenge text into a string in the format of

```
const rounds = 'B Y\n'+
'A X\n'+
'B Y\n'+
'A Y\n'+
'A Z\n'+
'B Y\n'+
'B Z\n'+
'C Y\n'+
'A X;
```

[Here](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/2/input) is the link to the full input

It creates issues when running a forEach and for loop with the whole dataset after splitting the string using Array.prototype.split(\n). The issue it is causing is the first index starts at around 1500 and ends 2500 for a dataset of about 5000 values. This is my solution to the [challenge](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/2)

```
import rounds from "./rounds.js";

const choiceMap = {
  A: {
    type: "Rock",
    points: 1,
  },
  B: {
    type: "Paper",
    points: 2,
  },
  C: {
    type: "Scissors",
    points: 3,
  },
  Y: {
    type: "Rock",
    points: 1,
  },
  X: {
    type: "Paper",
    points: 2,
  },
  Z: {
    type: "Scissors",
    points: 3,
  },
};

const pointMap = {
  Rock: {
    win: "Scissors",
    loss: "Paper",
  },
  Scissors: {
    win: "Paper",
    loss: "Rock",
  },
  Paper: {
    win: "Rock",
    loss: "Scissors",
  },
};

class RockPaperScissors {
  constructor(rounds) {
    this.rounds = rounds.trim().split("\n");
  }
  determinePoints = (choice, opponentChoice) => {
    let points = 0;
    choice = choiceMap[choice];
    opponentChoice = choiceMap[opponentChoice];
    points += choice.points;

    if (pointMap[choice.type].win === opponentChoice.type) points += 6;
    else if (choice.type === opponentChoice.type) points += 3;

    return points;
  };
  getPoints() {
    let points = 0;

    this.rounds.forEach((round, index) => {
      if (index === 0) console.log("first round");
      console.log(round, index);
      const [opponentChoice, choice] = round.split(" ");
      points += this.determinePoints(choice, opponentChoice);
    });
    return points;
  }
}

const elfGames = new RockPaperScissors(rounds);
elfGames.getPoints();
```

This is the start of my console output showing that loop did not start and end in the right positions

```
B X 1499
B Z 1500
B Z 1501
B Y 1502
C Y 1503
B Y 1504
C Y 1505
B Y 1506
B Z 1507
...
B Z 2493
B Y 2494
C X 2495
B X 2496
C X 2497
A X 2498
B ZB Y 2499
```

As you've probably noticed theres an issue with the last line which cause my code to fail.

Could I get suggestions on how to deal with this large dataset?

Comment: Code does work when dataset is reduced

Comment: The problem must in the conversion of the given challenge text into the string `rounds`. This string should contain a `\n` after each round except the last, but that is probably not the case.

Comment: Please [edit] this question's title to be a "summary of the problem" as detailed in [ask]. We don't care that it came from some programming challenge, and we know that you have an issue with JavaScript and arrays from the tags, so the only information we get from the title as it stands is that the problem is somewhere in the processing, which is hardly unique on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Using `import rounds from "./rounds.js";` and a hand-built string like

```js
const rounds = 'B Y\n'+
'A X\n'+
'B Y\n'+
'A Y\n'+
'A Z\n'+
'B Y\n'+
'B Z\n'+
'C Y\n'+
'A X;
```

is a lot of work and prone to copy-paste errors, typos and formatting consistency issues. If you must do this, use template literal syntax so you don't have to manually add quotes, `+` signs and new lines:

```js
const rounds = `B Y
A X
B Y
A Y
A Z
B Y
B Z
C Y
A X`;
```

This will make it much easier to paste in the full dataset. Just make sure the start and end backticks are in the right spots. Be careful with `.trim()`--usually, only `.split("\n")` is necessary, but it depends on the format of the data. It seems safe here, but without seeing your actual code for the full dataset, I can't say for sure.

However, the standard approach that works for any language is to keep the data in a raw file and read it into the application at runtime. This way, there's no conversion step; you simply download the file from the server right to your disk, which ensures all the formatting is exactly as it should be, with no whitespace sneaking in at the start or rear.

Using an external file simplifies the code footprint, separating data from the logic and making it easier to use different inputs to the program. It's a burden to have to modify the source code each time you want to use a different input. For compiled languages, this is an even bigger headache. On most coding challenge websites, the input is provided via file or stdin, making hardcoding a non-option.

```js
import fs from "node:fs";

const rounds = fs.readFileSync("data.txt", {encoding: "ascii"});
```

Note that in most real-world applications, you'll want to use `fs.promises.readFile` to avoid locking the main thread on I/O, but for solving an algorithm challenge this isn't usually a concern, so I've given the quick and dirty approach that keeps your code fully synchronous.

Using the above file version, I see the tail logged correctly on the larger dataset:

```
...
C Y 2496
C X 2497
A Y 2498
A X 2499
```

...but I haven't checked your algorithm logic at all, so I'll leave that as an exercise.